# compile errors when trying to compile C

Tags: c

The code:

```
enum cell_contents checkMove[8][8];
```

The error:

```
warning: passing argument 2 of ‘test_for_winner’ from incompatible pointer type [enabled 
by default]
test_for_winner(&playerCurrent, &checkMove[8][8]);

note: expected ‘enum cell_contents (*)[8]’ but argument is of type ‘enum cell_contents *’
BOOLEAN test_for_winner(struct player * next_player,
```

I am new at C programming. What am I doing wrong here?

edit - test for winner code

```
BOOLEAN test_for_winner(struct player * next_player, enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH])
{
    BOOLEAN has_moves = TRUE;
    return has_moves;
}
```

Comment: This is not the code that is causing the issue.

Comment: The problem is in your declaration for test_for_winner.  How did you declare that function?

Comment: Use `test_for_winner(&playerCurrent, checkMove);`

Comment: you defined `BOOLEAN test_for_winner(struct player * next_player, 
enum cell_contents board[][BOARDWIDTH])` : call `test_for_winner(&playerCurrent, checkMove);`

Comment: My psychic powers tell me you want to invoke test_for_winner as `test_for_Winner(&playerCurrent, checkMove);`  But I can't be sure until you show how test_for_winner is declared.

Comment: Good that you fixed that, because not only is `&checkMove[8][8]` wrong, it also invokes undefined behavior for an array declared as `[8][8]`. Glad you fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by changing the function call to:

```
test_for_winner(&playerCurrent, checkMove);
```